# Commit and rollback Oracle transactions

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, transactionscope

I'm calling this proc in C# from oracle. I made the proc to return an error. In other words the proc fails and pv_error is populated with string and the rollback gets triggered, but doesn't work. I'm not sure why. So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
private void hhrcv_update_dc_grs_carton()
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "dc.hhrcv_update_dc_grs_carton";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_dc_grs_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = txtDcGRSNo.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_pallet_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = txtPalletId.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_carton_code", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCartonCode.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_company_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = Companyid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_order_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = txtOrderno.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_emp_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = empid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pv_error", OracleDbType.VarChar));
        cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        string pv_error;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        pv_error = cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value.ToString();

        if (pv_error.ToString() == "")
        {
            trans.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show("" + pv_error, "Error");
            frmReturns r = new frmReturns();
            r.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

1. The stored Procedure is not committing
2. Oracle SQL developers autocommit is disabled
3. When I run the stored procedure in Oracle SQL developers it works (fails - like I have made it and doesn't commit)
4. Only when running the stored procedure in VS2005 the proc fails, triggers the rollback but doesn't execute it

Comment: _Just a tip_: Make your methods more readable!

Comment: What doesn't work? Maybe it's because you're not disposing the transaction. Use a using-statement to make sure it gets disposed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: The rollback doesn't work. It still executes the procedure and commits it even though it triggers the Rollback

Comment: I can think of two reasons 1. Autocommit 2. Stored procedure commits data itself

Comment: The stored procedure is definitely not committing. You saying oracle auto commits? How can I check this and disable it?

Comment: Probably is connection attribute (at least it's so in JDBC)

Comment: Autocommit is not checked in my Oracle SQL Developer client

Comment: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~AutoCommit.html

Answer (score 9):

Most likely you need to add:

```
cmd.Transaction = tran;
```

after calling `BeginTransaction`.

Without this the runtime does not know that `cmd` is part of the transaction `tran`!

For details see [the documentation](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~BeginTransaction%28%29.html).

Comment: Did not work for me :-( But even without this, `cmd` and `tran` already know about each other because `tran=conn.BeginTransaction()` and `cmd=new OracleCommand(...sql..., conn)`

Comment: the alternative is to create the command after creating the transaction -- the command will automatically participate in the active transaction

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in comment, I Highly reccommend checking connection's Autocommit property.

As Oracle's documentation states

> This property determines if Commit is called for the current
>   transaction after the execution of each SQL statement; otherwise,
>   false. **The default value is true.**

So at least try

```
conn.Autocommit=false;
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I have tried that and a couple of other possibilities. Unfortunately it doesn't work but I have asked Devart support/forum. Will post their answer here when I get it.

Comment: This probably relates to the Microsoft's `System.Data.OracleClient`, not Oracle's `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`